# PHP - Pagination Picks Correct Number of Pages, But Doesn't Divide Up Rows

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

The code below is an attempt at pagination.  It doesn't quite work.  I am playing around with a result that has 49 rows.  If I use `$rowsperpage = 10;`, the code below will correctly have hyperlinks to 4 pages at the bottom.  However, it still displays all 49 rows on page one, and clicking on the subsequent pages returns a blank page.

So my question is: how do I get the code below to correctly divide and allocate the rows amongst the pages following page 1?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<?
    //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form
    if ($searching =="yes")
    {

        //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
        if ($find == "")
        {
            session_write_close();
            header("Location:http://www.example.com/index.php");
            exit;
            unset($_SESSION['find']);   

        }

        // Otherwise we connect to our Database
        mysql_connect("mysqlv10", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

        // We preform a bit of filtering

        $find = strip_tags($find);
        $find = trim ($find);
        $find = strtolower($find);
        $find = mysql_real_escape_string($find);

        $result=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM database LIKE '$find'")
        or die(mysql_error());

        $_GET['result'] = $result;

        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            while($table=mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                $_GET[`$table[0]`] = $table;
                $_SESSION['table']= $table;

                $presult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table[0]`") or die(mysql_error());

                $rr = mysql_fetch_row($presult);  
                $numrows = $rr[0]; 
                $rowsperpage = 50; 
                $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

                // get the current page or set a default  
                if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {  
                   // cast var as int  
                   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];  
                } else {  
                   // default page num  
                   $currentpage = 1;  
                } // end if  

                // if current page is greater than total pages...  
                if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {  
                   // set current page to last page  
                   $currentpage = $totalpages;  
                } // end if  
                // if current page is less than first page...  
                if ($currentpage < 1) {  
                   // set current page to first page  
                   $currentpage = 1;  
                } // end if  

                // the offset of the list, based on current page   
                $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage; 

                print "<p class=\"topic\">$table[0]</p>\n";
                $r=mysql_query("SELECT * , votes_up - votes_down AS effective_vote FROM `$table[0]` ORDER BY effective_vote DESC");

                $_GET[`$r[0]`] = $r;

                print "<table class=\"navbar\">\n";
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){

                    $_GET[`$row[0]`] = $row;
                    $_SESSION['row']= $row;

                    $effective_vote = $row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down']; 

                    print "<tr>";

                    print "<td class='sitename'>".'<a href="http://'.$row['site'].'" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'."</td>";
                    print "<td class='votes'>".'<span class="selection_count" id="selection_count'.$row['id'].'">'.number_format($effective_vote).'</span>'."</td>";
                    print "<td class='ballot'>".'<span class="button" id="button'.$row['id'].'">'.'<a href="javascript:;" class="cell1" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.Select.'</a>'.'</span>'."</td>";
                }
                print "</tr>\n";
            }
            print "</table>\n";

            $range = 3;  

            /******  build the pagination links ******/  
            // range of num links to show    

            // if not on page 1, don't show back links  
            if ($currentpage > 1) {  
               // show << link to go back to page 1  
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&find={$_SESSION['find']}'><<</a> ";  
               // get previous page num  
               $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;  
               // show < link to go back to 1 page  
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage&find={$_SESSION['find']}'><</a> ";  
            } // end if   

            // loop to show links to range of pages around current page  
            for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {  
               // if it's a valid page number...  
               if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {  
                  // if we're on current page...  
                  if ($x == $currentpage) {  
                     // 'highlight' it but don't make a link  
                     echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";  
                  // if not current page...  
                  } else {  
                     // make it a link  
                 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x&find={$_SESSION['find']}'>$x</a> ";  
                  } // end else  
               } // end if   
            } // end for  

            // if not on last page, show forward and last page links      
            if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {   
               // get next page  
               $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;  
                // echo forward link for next page   
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage&find={$_SESSION['find']}'>></a> ";  
               // echo forward link for lastpage  
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages&find={$_SESSION['find']}'>>></a> ";  
            } // end if  
            /****** end build pagination links ******/

        }
        else{
            print "";
        }

        //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that
        $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($anymatches == 0)
        {

            $find = urlencode($find);

            session_write_close();
            header("Location:http://www.example.com/search2.php?find=$find");
            exit;

        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: the main thing is to use limit in your mysql query

Comment: OK, I added "LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage", and now page one looks perfect, with the correct number of rows.  But then when I click on the following pages, they are blank.  Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: I think my problem is that $find is not being passed to the subsequent links.  But I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Comment: save $find if is set in a session and u can use it in all links

Comment: I'm already doing that.  At the end of the page link URL, I have "?currentpage=$nextpage&find={$_SESSION['find']}", and when I click on the link, the URL is correct, but the page is blank.  However, I am using <?php echo $find;?> in my <title>, and here, $find is blank.

Comment: Then that's a separate problem than what's in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use limit to get specific items from your table.

```
select * form table limit 5, 10
```

That will start at element 5 in the query and return the next 10 items.

Usually for pagination you want to do something like

```
select * from table limit (PAGE-1)*ITEMS_PER_PAGE, ITEMS_PER_PAGE
```

[mysql's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)